# SelectNodes from IXmlNode returns an empty XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xpath, win-universal-app, xmldocument, empty-list

I am writing a Windows Universal App and have to parse HTML-Code and extract data with XPath. (I am using the XmlDocument from Windows.Data.Xml.Dom)

So when I select a single Node ("nPostingsRoot"), I am getting a node with some childnodes. But when I am trying get a list of all  Tags in the root of this single node, I got an empty List. (please refer screenshot)

To iterate through the Childnodes isn't an option, because I have later some XPaths strings like this: `/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/b[1]`

Can someone help me?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxwVv.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows an XPath `/div` which would look for `div` child elements of the document node. In an HTML document the only child element of the document node is an `html` element. If you want the `div` child elements of a context node simply use the path `div`, if you want the descendants use `descendant::div` or `.//div`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Martin Honnen. In addition, If you want to parse the Html Code, I recommend you to use [HtmlAgilityPack for .NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore/).

I came across a few problem when I use XmlDocument to parse the Html (I have to remove or comment out the `<!DOCTYPE html>` to successfully parse the html codes). But there is no such problem while using HtmlAgilityPack.

To get the Div under the rootNode you can use the codes below using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
HtmlNode rootNode =htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div");
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> collection=rootNode.Descendants("div");
```

or you can use XPath to get the child div Nodes like this:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
HtmlNode rootNode =htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div");
HtmlNodeCollection collection = rootNode.SelectNodes("div");
```

And here is my complete [Demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/ParseHtmlSample)